# How to convert a string to an array with JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, regex, typescript

How can I convert a string (which is actually an ordered list) to an array using JavaScript / TypeScript? Unfortunately, this is what the backend returns.

The string looks like this:

1. Lorem Ipsum. 2. Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum.

I want an array like this:

```
[
  '1. Lorem Ipsum.',
  '2. Lorem Ipsum.',
  '3. Lorem Ipsum.'
]
```

..in order to use it like this in my Angular template:

```
<div>
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let entry of entries">{{entry}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I already tried it with `split()` and `JSON.parse()`.. I don't know what character to use to split the array.

For example `console.log (this.entries.split (''));` returns an array with each word of the string. I also tried using other characters to split the string but I can't find the right one.

Comment: you already tried with split, and why is it not working ?

Comment: can you modify the string ? so you can add spesific delimeter for `split()`.

Comment: You can use split() and "pop" the index strings.

Comment: @RapSherlock No, currently the API returns the string like this :(

Comment: @Vucko Hmm, how?

Comment: That is not really good if backend return string like that ! You just should fix backend data return

Comment: I agree with @DavidJawHpan still, if you want a temporary solution, check the solution below.

Comment: @DavidJawHpan I know and agree. Have to contact to backend devs for that but currently a solution for this scenario is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : Use also [positive lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Other_assertions) to keep the 1. 2. 3.

There might be better regex ( I am very bad at regex )
but this do the trick for this precise exemple, the solution all depend on the regex you apply. but the method to use is split.

```
var text = "1. Lorem Ipsum. 2. Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum.";
var regex = new RegExp("(?=[0-9].)"); 
text.split(regex);
```

=> OUTPUT

```
Array(3) [ "1. Lorem Ipsum. ", "2. Lorem Ipsum. ", "3. Lorem Ipsum." ]
```

Comment: Several suggested solutions worked, but I'll use your approach until the backend returns a clean array. Many Thanks!

Comment: Just be wary that without using a whitespace match (like in my solution below :P ), you will end up with items of varying patterns in the array i.e., in the example above, the first two items end with a whitespace but the last one doesn't. Depending on your use case, this may or may not affect you.

Comment: you can always `trim` the result, but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
console.log("1. Lorem Ipsum. 2. Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum.".match(/\d+\D+/g))
```

Comment: you can use also `[0-9]\.([A-Za-z\ ])+\.` to "trim" the array

Comment: Can you please explain the regex?

Comment: \d+ starts with a number and \D+ takes every none-number after. --> a number starts a new finding. The g makes this regex global and finds all matches

Comment: @Codehan25, in this page:https://regex101.com/ you can check any regExpr, if mouse over the reg expr show a tool-tip with a brief description of each Expresion

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot have a better end of sentence then your current `.` you will have to building some smart splinting and filtering

something like this works:

```
text = "1. Lorem Ipsum. 2. Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum."
arr = text.split(".")
res = text.split(".").map((item, i)=> (i%2 === 0) ? `${item}.${arr[i+1]}.` : "undefined" ).filter(item=> !item.includes("undefined"))
```

obliviously this is not optimized, but i am sure you can start from there

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect it to get so complex ^^. They really need to change the backend ^^.

Comment: regex is also a way to do this, as per other answers, but you are absolutely right. get them to send an array from the back-end is the best answer. They could at least send a better end-of-sentence then a `.`... so you could for example do a "1. Lorem Ipsum;2. Lorem Ipsum;3. Lorem Ipsum.".split(';') to get an array

Comment: That's how it will end. Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
var a = '1. Lorem Ipsum. 2. Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum.';
var split = a.split(/\s(?=[0-9]/);
console.log('output',split); // Prints: ["1. Lorem Ipsum.", "2. Lorem Ipsum.", "3. Lorem Ipsum."]
```

The regex basically says:

`\s` - Match a whitespace character.

`(?=[0-9])` - Look (on positive side - meaning forward) for a numeric character.

The `.split()` method applies the split on a match. But the lookahead is necessary to ascertain that a number exists after the match.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be the exact answer to the question but just in case someone wants to convert a a string to an array of individual characters, you can try out the spread operator as shown instead of the 'quanky' loops

const myString = 'a very good programmer'

const myStringArr = [...myString]

console.log(myStringArr)
['a', ' ', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'y', ' ', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', ' ', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'm', 'e', 'r']